# error using git push

Tags: git, heroku, push

I try running git push and get the following error. This is my first time trying to host an app on Heroku. Please help.

Error Message:

[image]

Folder Contents:

[image]

Comment: I guess you have to push something that is 'compilable' for the push to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Please see my folder contents in the above image

Comment: What exactly was your `push ...` command? you can check with `git remote show origin` whether the remote is ok.

Comment: 'git push heroku master'. when i run 'git remote show origin' i get fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: git remote shows heroku

Comment: Your push was rejected by the pre-receive hook in the server repo. This is not a git issue. It seems some file is ill-formatted or missing in the pushed revision. You could ask the repo owner for more info and help.

Comment: If you want to address somebody, use e.g. `@Christoph`. I only saw your message by accident... As ElpieKay says: Have a look at the pre-commit hook, as `git remote show ...` says that the repo is known.